# boolean algebra simple question

Tags: boolean-algebra

Simplfy : 
$$
(x+y)\cdot(x+yz) 
$$
I have tried to solve the question through by evaluating the expressions $x(x+y)$ and $yz(x+y)$ but I didn't get the right answer which is: 
$$
(x+y)\cdot(x+yz)=x + yz
$$

Comment: You have started with [distributivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra#Laws) : thus, you have to write the complete equation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you can use the negation trick and use DeMorgan-rules:

- Set $\bar E = \overline{(x+y)\cdot(x+yz)}$
  $$\Rightarrow \bar E =\bar x \bar y + \bar x (\bar y + \bar z) = \bar x(\bar y + \bar z) \Rightarrow E = x + yz$$

Comment: thank you , one more thing can i do something like that ? : (x+y)(x+z) = x(x+y) + z(x+y)  like basic algebra or is it wrong

Comment: @RaziAwad Yes. You can do that.

Answer (score 3):

Hint:

$$a\cdot a=a$$

$$b+b= b$$

$$xyz+yz=yz(x+1)=?$$

Answer (score 1):

Another way to look at this problem:

$Y\cap Z\subseteq Y$ so that $X\cup (Y\cap Z)\subseteq X\cup Y$ or equivalently:$$(X\cup Y)\cap(X\cup(Y\cap Z))=X\cup (Y\cap Z)$$

Translation gives:$$(x+y)\cdot(x+y\cdot z)=x+y\cdot z$$

Answer (score 0):

With the use of the second distributivity law D2 we have 
$$x+yz=(x+y)\cdot (x+z),$$ from where 
$$\begin{aligned}(x+y)\cdot(x+yz)&=(x+y)\cdot (x+y)\cdot(x+z)\\&=(x+y)\cdot (x+z)\\&=x+yz, \end{aligned}$$
the last step again by D2.